# Memory pointer cleared when returned with object

Tags: c++

This has been destroying me for a while. I'm sure there's a reason for this:

```
chain operator+(chain c)
{
    chain<Object> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
    {
        result.insert(*(Object*)(memory+(i*sizeof(Object))));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
    {
        result.insert(c[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) // This for loop successfully shows all objects in result
    {
        cout << result[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

When the value is returned, ie:

```
chain<int> a;
cin >> a; // enter "5 6 7 8"
chain<int> b;
cin >> b; // enter "9 10 11 12"
chain <int> c = a+b;

cout << c; // Returns "0 0 7 8 9 10 11 12"
```

The first two numbers are always 0. I can't figure out why. This only happens when adding two chains together; if I cout a or b, I get all of the values.

I would really appreciate it if anyone has any info to share :)

EDIT**

Full Source

```
#ifndef CHAIN_H
#define CHAIN_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <class Object>
class chain
{
    public:
            chain(){
                    memorySize = 8;
                    memory = calloc(memorySize, sizeof(Object));
                    count = 0;
            }
            chain(Object item){
                    memorySize = 8;
                    memory = calloc(memorySize, sizeof(Object));
                    count = 0;
                    insert(item);
            }
            chain(chain & original){
                    memorySize = 8;
                    memory = calloc(memorySize, sizeof(Object));
                    count = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
                    {
                            insert(original[i]);
                    }
            }
            ~chain(){
                    free(memory);
            }
                chain operator+(chain c){
                    chain<Object> result;
                    for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
                    {
                            result.insert(this->operator[](i));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
                    {
                            result.insert(c[i]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
                    {
                            cout << result[i];
                    }
                    return result;
            }
            Object & operator[](int pos){
                    return *(Object*)(memory+(pos*sizeof(Object)));
            }
            int length(){
                    return count;
            }
            void insert(Object item){
                    if (count == memorySize)
                    {
                            doubleMemory();
                    }
                    this->operator[](count) = item;
                    count++;
            }
    private:
            int count;
            int memorySize;
            void * memory;
            void doubleMemory(){
                    memorySize *= 2;
                    memory = realloc(memory, (memorySize*sizeof(Object)));
            }

};
template <class Object>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, chain<Object>& c){
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++)
    {
            out << c[i] << " ";
    }
}
template <class Object>
istream& operator>>(istream& in, chain<Object>& c){
    char ch;
    int number = 0;
    int sign;
    while(ch != '\n')
    {
            ch = in.get();
            if (ch == '-')
            {
                    sign = 1;
            }
            else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            {
                    number *= 10;
                    number += (ch-48);
            }
            else if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
            {
                    number = sign == 1? 0 - number : number;
                    c.insert(number);
                    sign = 0;
                    number = 0;
            }
    }
}
#endif
```

Here's the code I'm testing against:

```
#include "chain.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    chain<int> a, b, c;
    chain<int> d(10);
    chain<int> e(d);
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    c = a+d;
    cout << c;
}
```

~

Comment: The problem may not be in `operator+`, it may be in your copy c'tor or `operator<<`. Can you post those as well?

Comment: You may get more help if you provided a complete example that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: Luchian deleted his answer – but I would *not* use his solution of `this->operator[](i)` … much too convoluted syntax. Use `(*this)[i]` instead.

Comment: What is the class definition of `chain`?

Comment: Why do you not copy `count` in copy-constructor?

Comment: @fasked: `count` is set properly  through calls to insert method

Comment: @nyarlathotep It's an error. For example, I created `chain<int> a` and inserted into it 10 integers, then I created `chain<int> b = a`. What will `b.length()` return?

Comment: In VC++ 2010 it won't even compile. Complains about `error C2036: 'void *' : unknown size` in operator[]...

Comment: @fasked: copy c'tor called for that case; insert is called 10 times in there, so, b.length()=10. For the general assignment though this won't work of course since operator= is not defined as Konrad Rudolph states.

Comment: it would also do good to listen to compiler warnings - operator<< and operator>> don't return any value, and ch is used uninitialized, same goes for sign (and there bool would be better suited)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you’ve shown isn’t the problem. The real problem is probably either in the copy constructor or the destructor of `chain` – maybe also in the `insert` method (or, on C++11, in the move constructor).

(It could also be in `Object`’s copy constructor but I think that’s unlikely.)

---

EDIT: Oh my. Don’t write such code in C++. It’s unsafe left, right and center. As long as `Object` is a POD you should be fine but if it isn’t this code yields undefined behaviour. In particular, it doesn’t call the proper constructors and destructors for the objects you store in your chain.

Furthermore, your copy constructor should take an argument of type `chain const&` since you’re not modifying the passed `chain`. This in turn requires that you make your class const correct by providing an appropriate `const` overload of `operator []`.

Finally and most glaringly, you violate the rule of three because you don’t implement `operator =` for your `chain`. Trying to assign one `chain` to another will consequently result in double frees.

Generally avoid `calloc` and `free` and use a standard container instead, or, if that’s not an option, use `new[]` plus a smart pointer like [boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) to manage memory (but *do not* use `delete[]`).

Another thing, never use `using namespace` in a header file, it will pollute the namespace and lead to name conflicts in the weirdest places.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Seems like **Rule of Three** not being followed properly. Perhaps, error in one of the big three's.

Comment: I've updated with full source. Trying to dig through other stuff to see what I missed...

Comment: Updating my code with your suggested changes. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: another suggestion would be to make operator+ a non-member, so that it can be used more easily with convertible types (see Scott Meyers, Effective C++, 3rd Edition, Item 24)

Comment: and aonther one: operator+ also should take its chain parameter by const reference, not by value

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see the following problem regarding the copy-constructor. It seems to me that you want this to act as a copy-constructor:

```
chain(chain & original){
    memorySize = 8;
    memory = calloc(memorySize, sizeof(Object));
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++)
    {
        insert(original[i]);
    }
}
```

But it can't since the declaration of the method is wrong. You are missing the const modifier in the copy argument. If you don't include it, the compiler assumes that you are only declaring a normal constructor which works with a mutable reference, and this is not the copy-constructor you need to define following the 
[Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Just change this:

```
chain(chain & original){
```

to this:

```
chain(const chain & original){
```

This will probably solve a wrong memory handling, and hopefully you will get a different output in your program.

Comment: That's just a really small part of the problem, and it's mentioned in Konrad Rudolph's answer for quite some time already :(

Comment: Yes Konrad Rudolph's answer is much more complete, didn't see it by the time I wrote mine.